# php - quick help needed with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm parsing rss feeds however some feeds have what look to be blank images in them (from feedburner). Can somewhere help me out with a preg_replace command to find and remove an image tag structured like:

```
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/sdfasdfsfd" height="1" width="1"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Why you can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Remove an image tag? You mean, remove everything from `<img` to `/>` ?

Comment: Why do people always suggest using HTML parsers, whenever someone wants to match/replace something within some html code? Using regular expressions to replace *regular* occurences within some html code is completely fine..

Comment: @poke: Because [The <center> cannot hold it is too late](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @ircmaxell: Might want to read the question and my comment again? This is not about parsing HTML; it is about removing some *regular text* from a string that might contain html tags.

Comment: @poke: Again, that's assuming that this text is regular.  It would be quite trivial to write some HTML that would miss most HTML purifiers, but would be turned into something harmful with a regex like this.  So this is about parsing HTML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the "sdfasdfsfd" is something random:

```
$text = preg_replace( '#<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/[a-z]+" height="1" width="1"/>#i', '', $text );
```